# Change text with jQuery then change again

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an ajaxified Woocommerce 'Add to cart' button which adds the product to the cart. The text on the button changes to 'Added to cart'. After a delay of say, 3 seconds I would like to change it back to 'Add to cart'.

```
if( response.success ) {
    $this.text("added to cart");
    $( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_fragment_refresh' );
    $this.delay(5000).text("Add to cart");
    $('.gift-with-coupon').slideUp();
}
```

I have tried this, a while the product is added to the cart via Ajax, the text doesn't got from 'Add to cart - Added to cart - Add to cart'. It just skips the middle one. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

use wp_enqueue_script() to add a JS file to your theme

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        jQuery(this).text('Added to cart');
       window.setTimeout(function () {
               jQuery(".single_add_to_cart_button").text('Add to cart');
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

it's tested and working fine so please check for your site